# How can I display and close a View from a Controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I simply want to display a "CreditsView". So if i press a button show a credits view, press ok the view will disappear.

I have my base controller and my credits view controller and now i try something like:

```
- (IBAction)switchToCreditsView:(id)sender {
creditsViewController = [[CreditsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreditsViewController"];
[self.view addSubview:creditsViewController.view];
//[self presentModalViewController:creditsViewController animated:YES];
```

}

But if i press the Button my app crashed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To go back you simply call:

```
- (IBAction)switchToBaseView:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the questions seems to stupid to ask ;)

Thanks, it works now!
(switchToBaseView has to be placed in the CreditsViewController, just to complete this here :) )

Answer (score 3):

To switch back do this

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
And then free the view if you want.
[self release];